# A bit of assistance with sub and regex

Tags: regex, ruby-on-rails-3

This works:

```
'http://foobar.com/default_profile_images/default_profile_6_normal.png'.sub(/normal\.([a-z]+)$/, 'reasonably_small.\1')
```

This doesn't:

```
"http://foobar.com/profile_images/1550660558/Bathurze_Pics_normal.JPG".sub(/normal\.([a-z]+)$/, 'reasonably_small.\1')
```

I'm trying to substitute `normal` with `reasonably small`. Anyone know why it doesnt work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a case sensitive issue.  JPG isn't matched by [a-z].  If you change your regex to be case insensitive it should work.

Change `/normal\.([a-z]+)$/`
to `/normal\.([a-z]+)$/i` (added the `i` modifier)

Comment: Are there any implications if I do `/normal\./` ?

Comment: Probably not.  The only implication would be if it matched somewhere else in the file name, but most files don't use a period as a separator so you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

The second example has uppercase letters at the ending, so you should change your regexpression from

`/normal\.([a-z]+)$/` to

`/normal\.([a-zA-Z]+)$/`

Edit: Fixed missing + in second regex

Answer (score 0):

added case handling -

```
"http://foobar.com/profile_images/1550660558/Bathurze_Pics_normal.JPG".sub(/normal\.([a-z]+)$/, 'reasonably_small.\1')
```

Should work.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is /[a-z]+/ only catch small letters, in other word it is case sensitive.

As the file suffix in first example is .png so, the regex match, while the second doesn't.

The solution can simply change it from [a-z]+ to [A-Za-z+].